# What character must be used as decimal seperator for the ratingValue property?

Tags: schema.org

I'm using Schema.org markup in my website and want to add `AggregateRating` to the posts, but in `ratingValue` property which character should I use to separate in decimal numbers?

For example rating system is 5-scale (`worstRating` = 1 and `bestRating` = 5) and `ratingValue` is 5٫00 or 5٫26.

Is using the character `٫` OK? `٫` or `,` or `.`? The plugin I use inserts `٫` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to https://schema.org/AggregateRating and can easily see the confusion. The ratingValue says *text* whereas *bestRating* and *worstRating* says *number* or *text*. If you click the links for *text* or *number*, the information provided does not help clarify your question.

Yikes!!

I did look at the second Microdata example for AggregateRating where the value for ratingValue is 3.5 and it does use a . (period). I realize that for some locales, it is perfectly acceptable to use a , (comma), however, I would recommend a . (period) just to be sure.

You can certainly try both, one at a time, and check it using https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ to validate the code via Google.

Comment: I looked at some world wide webs like imdb and saw that they use . (period) so I'll use this one :) thanks.

Comment: @Amirreza Nasiri Anytime! We are here for you. Cheers!!